# Accessing XML response in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a very simple Chrome extension and am getting stuck while trying to make an XML request in order to access the data on current tab.

As is, I can get the extension to access the tab data, including the URL, when the extension icon is clicked. When it does so, it runs the `background.js` script. But I can only get as far as sending the request, never accessing the response. I have tried about as much as I can think of, but checking the `.readyState` attribute tells me the request is not getting done. Any thoughts?

For now I'm just trying to output to the console to show that I'm getting the data in a form in which I can use it, I'll flesh out what I'm going to do with it later.

Extension files below:

manifest.json

```
{"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ThisIsATest",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions" : [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"],
    "persistent" : false
  },
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_title" : "Log Page Source Code"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    console.log('Getting URL: ' + tab.url);
    var xreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(xreq.readyState);
    xreq.open('GET', tab.url);
    console.log(xreq.readyState);
    xreq.responseType = "text";
    xreq.send();
    console.log(xreq.response);
});
```

Comment: This is not how XHR is used. You need to use its `load` event or `readystatechange`. Look for examples, there are tons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the response, because it can take a while:

```
xreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xreq.open('GET', tab.url);
xreq.onload = function () {
    console.log(xreq.response);
}
xreq.send();
```

You could also just use fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch since it's way easier.